# Excel - Summary count of multi-column duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to wrap my head around an answer for this. I can find duplicates when using a formula that looks at a single sell and compare it to a range of cells, and copy that formula down every row; afterward I can just sum the results. However, I want a single formula in a single cell.

I want to take a range of cells in one column, compare that entire set to a range of cells in another column, and sum all duplicate cells where the cell in column 1 matches a cell in column 2. For this exercise, all cells in each column are unique within that column, they are only potentially duplicate between columns.

For example:

```
    C1 C2
R1   1  2
R2   2  6
R3   3  7
R4   4  1
R5   5  8
```

I want a single column sum with a result of 2 (the duplicate cells in C1 is 1 and 2).

This will ultimately be converted into a VBA script however I can work with starting with a single formula. If starting out at VBA is easier then that works for me too.

My specific question is: which functions in excel do I use to accomplish this task?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the formula you want in cell `C3` is:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,$B$1:$B$5,1,FALSE)),0,1)
```

This will return a 1 if your column-1 value appears in column 2, and a 0 if it doesn't. Then you can simply copy it down for the extent of your data (changing the referenced range as needed) sum the results of column 3. (Note that the `FALSE` is important as it forces exact matches; otherwise, Excel will display approximate matches, which will compromise the accuracy of your results.)

Comment: thanks but what I was trying to say was that I already knew this part. What i'm looking for is a single function that is not copied down. E.g. R0 C1 would say 2; I don't want a C3. I'm thinking at this point that maybe a VBA script with some variables and a loop would be the best way to figure this out. Really, I'm trying to automate some calculations for a coworker and hand over to her a one-click operation