# Excel Formula: check for every Col1 unique value, if COL2 has duplicates, then Col3 should not be unique

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

Consider the following data. I have added help text across each data row to explain scenarios: Bill is Col A, Ref is col B and so on

Form: is Formula; Exceptns: With Current Formula the results I get and expected output is what I'm looking at

```
Bill    Ref Ref2    HelpText    Form    Form    Excptns Excepted output
123     557 123     Scenario1   1       1       FALSE   FALSE
123     589 123-1   Scenario1   1       1       FALSE   FALSE
123     591 123-2   Scenario1   2       1       TRUE    FALSE
123     591 123-3   Scenario2   2       1       TRUE    TRUE
124     432 124     Scenario1   1       1       FALSE   FALSE
124     433 124-1   Scenario1   1       1       FALSE   FALSE
```

Scenario1:

Since they have same bill number and unique Ref Number, Ref2 column has to be unique

Scenario2:

Since same bill number and same ref number, we can't have unique Ref2 values - therefore (it should be 123-2 and not 123-3 and I need to identify all such cases using excel formula)

Duplicates scenario will not exist as we are taking pivot

My effort:

```
     A    B   C          D             E                      F            G
    Bill REf Ref2       HelpText      Formula                Formula      Formul
    123  557 123        Scenario1     =countIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)
    123  589 123-1      Scenario1
    123  591 123-2      Scenario1
    123  592 123-2      Scenario2
```

1. I used `countifs(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)` in columnE
2. `countifs(B:B,B2,C:C,C2)` in columnF
3. columnG FORMULA is `=AND(IF(E2>1,"TRUE","FALSE"),IF(F2=1,"TRUE","FALSE"))`

when I FILTER Column G by true/false - true means exceptions:
I get both instances as output. I'm however not interested at the first occurrence because it's valid. From there on, 2nd and incase 3rd instances - I will be interested

Please help me arriving at the formula of how can I can ignore the first occurrence. I can not use VBA. Only excel formulae - and no limit on column numbers

Comment: Have you searched on here already? This may help : https://stackoverflow.com/q/19793946/4961700

Comment: Hi @SolarMike the link you have shared is for identifying Column1 duplicates in Column2, my intention is to check for every C1 unique value, if COL2 has duplicates, then Col3 should not be unique

Comment: So adapt the technique...